# Azure Graph API - Multiple web platforms redirect URL not working

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with Azure Graph API and it works well when I configure only one web platform having one redirect URL.

When I add multiple Web platforms and having multiple redirect URLs, it always redirects back to the last/latest redirect URLs.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cACJH.png)

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app) {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            
            var _Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
            var RedirectUri = _Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:RedirectUri").Value;

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            OwinTokenAcquirerFactory factory = TokenAcquirerFactory.GetDefaultInstance<OwinTokenAcquirerFactory>();
            
            app.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(factory);
            factory.Services
                .Configure<ConfidentialClientApplicationOptions>(options => { options.RedirectUri = RedirectUri; })
                .AddMicrosoftGraph()
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
            factory.Build();
        }
```

```
// Sign in


            if (!Request.IsAuthenticated) {
                var context = HttpContext.GetOwinContext();
                context.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });
                context.Authentication.Challenge(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = RedirectUri },
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
            }
```

As I have multiple url configured, it should work with different application hosted.

Comment: `var RedirectUri = _Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd:RedirectUri").Value;` does the redirect url equal to the one you set in Azure AD portal?

Comment: Yes, it is the same one from the list of the URL I have set in Azure AD Portal